# Clean Array of strings

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say i have an array as such

```
var documentPredicateValues= [
  "http://schema.org/", 
  "http://schema.org/MusicEvent", 
  "_:2", 
  "_:3", 
  "Shostakovich Leningrad", 
  "2014-05-23T20:00",
  "_:4", "_:6", 
  "http://schema.org/MusicVenue", 
  "Chicago Symphony Center",
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_Center",
  "220 S. Michigan Ave, Chicago, Illinois, USA", 
  "http://schema.org/Offer", 
  "file:///examples/ticket/12341234", 
  "40", 
  "USD", 
  "http://schema.org/InStock", 
  "http://schema.org/CreativeWork", 
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Grimes", 
  "Britten Four Sea Interludes and Passacaglia from Peter Grimes", 
  "http://schema.org/CreativeWork", 
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._7_(Shostakovich)", 
  "Shostakovich Symphony No. 7 (Leningrad)", 
  "http://schema.org/MusicGroup", 
  "http://cso.org/", 
  "file:///C:/Users/Ben/Desktop/Visualizaing%20Linked…ptimised(RDFA%20query)/examples/Performer?id=4434", 
  "http://schema.org/Person", 
  "http://www.jaapvanzweden.com/", 
  "file:///examples/jvanzweden_s.jpg", 
  "file:///examples/Performer.aspx?id=11324"
];
```

I simply wish to 'clean' any string values which start with 'file' until the last Index of '/' i have a snippet of code (below) which finds each of those strings starting with file however whenever i try to do a substring and cut the unwanted characters off it applies to everything like so:

```
for(var p =0; p < documentPredicateValues.length; p++)
{       

cleaned.push(documentPredicateValues[p].substring(documentPredicateValues[p].lastIndexOf("/")+1, documentPredicateValues[p].length));  
}
```

and the result is

```
[
   "", 
  "MusicEvent", 
  "_:2", 
  "_:3", 
  "Shostakovich Leningrad", 
  "2014-05-23T20:00", 
  "_:4", 
  "_:6", 
  "MusicVenue", 
  "Chicago Symphony Center", 
  "Symphony_Center", 
  "220 S. Michigan Ave, Chicago, Illinois, USA", 
  "Offer", 
  "12341234", 
  "40", 
  "USD", 
  "InStock", 
  "CreativeWork", 
  "Peter_Grimes", 
  "Britten Four Sea Interludes and Passacaglia from Peter Grimes", 
  "CreativeWork", 
  "Symphony_No._7_(Shostakovich)", 
  "Shostakovich Symphony No. 7 (Leningrad)", 
  "MusicGroup", 
  "", 
  "Performer?id=4434", 
  "Person", 
  "", 
  "jvanzweden_s.jpg", 
  "Performer.aspx?id=11324", 
  "12341234", 
  "Performer?id=4434", 
  "jvanzweden_s.jpg", 
  "Performer.aspx?id=11324"
]
```

here is a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kt9zzx5d/2/

EDIT: Pasted in the wrong function. JS fiddle has been updated.

Comment: i think you will want `.map` or the result of `.filter`.

Comment: @Ben but there isn't a substring `file` at the start in this `http://schema.org/` element. Then why to removed it?

Comment: Can you be more clear on the problem here. Is it that the items that do not have "file" in their name is still being affected?

Comment: @Avinash Well e, is the the entire result of the string, so it goes through all values in e to find which values start with file.  Daniel, how'd i go about mapping it?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes you are correct, i just want to clean that Array's values which start with file, nothing more ^_^.

Comment: Your jsfiddle works correctly. It isn't producing the results you show in your question.

Comment: I'm also getting the correct results from your fiddle: `[ "12341234", "Performer?id=4434", "jvanzweden_s.jpg", "Performer.aspx?id=11324" ]`.

Comment: Ah sorry guys i just realised i've put the wrong piece of code in. It's been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using filter incorrectly.  Filter will return array element matching the predicate function, not for assigning stuffs.

Use this instead:

```
for (var i = 0, l = documentPredicateValues.length; i < l; i++) {
    var e = documentPredicateValues[i];

    documentPredicateValues[i] = e.substring(0,4) == "file" ? e.substring(e.lastIndexOf("/")+1, e.length) : e;
}
```

or this if you don't want to override original array:

```
var cleaned = documentPredicateValues.map(function(e) {
    return e.substring(0,4) == "file" ? e.substring(e.lastIndexOf("/")+1, e.length) : e;
});
```

Comment: Ah this works fantastically! Could you explain the use of the ? & :...? Also, nice use of caching the length.

Comment: It's ternary operator... check the expression ? true value to return : false value to return.  Shorthand for  if (condition) { return true value; } else { return false value; }

Comment: Ohhh i see this is brilliant! Thanks for the input i can use what you've shown me here on other piece of my very simple code haha - again thank you!